# Why can't Apple Aperture 3 upload raw files from my Canon 7D?

Tags: raw, apple-aperture, file-transfer

Whenever I try to import raw files from my Canon 7D using Apple Aperture 3 (which is fully updated with all the latest Software Updates) I get an upload of 350 unwanted images ( including corporate logos and the like ) attached to a whole variety of emails sent to me over a long period by third parties ( which it would be virtually impossible now to trace and delete from my emails ).

Whenever I seek to cancel this projected upload, repress the upload icon and switch on my Canon 7D to effect the upload from my Memory Card, I am unable to "bite' onto the Canon 7D icon which appears and the upload reverts to the 350 unwanted images.

This has also happened frequently with Jpegs and Raws + Jpegs but I have usually succeeded in overcoming the problem. Until a few months I shot with a Canon 40D with no such problem but I didn't used to shoot Raw only.

Is it possible that my Memory Cards have become corrupted in some way ? Contents had previously been transferred by a photolab in South Africa to SanDisks but only two of the cards were wiped and reformatted; and the problem relates to the inputting of Raws from ALL my cards. Can anybody help please?

Comment: What's the firmware version of your 7D, version of OS X, and version of Aperture?

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me if I'm far off, but when was the last time you updated your Mac through Software Update?

Apple keeps releasing "Digital RAW Compatibility Updates" that add support for new cameras.

The 7D got support in "Digital Camera RAW Compatibility Update 2.7."

Check http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1475.

Comment: Thanks; but as already indicated, I have already downloaded ALL  the published Updates and the problem remains. I will, however, double-check yet again. DG

Comment: In fairness, you mentioned that Aperture 3 was fully updated with all the latest software updates, but you didn't mention the patch level of OSX itself.

Comment: Thanks again but I'm afraid you've lost me. What is the "patch level of OSX" ? I've downloaded all Apple Aperture 3 Updates. My Imac is MAC 0SX build 11G63. Are you saying thee is something more I should do or explain ? DG

Comment: I should perhaps add that my MAC OSX software is fully up to date and there are no further Updates available which I have not downloaded DG

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that connecting my 7D directly to the computer using an USB cable did not work as expected. This was also with Aperture 3.

However, I have an external CF reader, where I pop in the memory card. And viola, everything reads in perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm using Aperture 3 import function to import raw from my 7D via. USB connection. No issue with importing.

Comment: Mnytks to u both and also again to Maxam. Having now had local IT help I seem to have solved the issue.Despite having uploaded all Apple and Aperture updates available on the relevant sites,  my local help (working through Teamviewer) uploaded or re-upoaded some raw conversion update from another site and I also changed the connecting cable on suspicion that its predecessor may have been faulty. One or other or both of these seems to have done the trick in enabling me to input Canon Raws; and now I need to learn how to do the same with Fuji X10 Raws, apparently unsupported by Aperture 3. DG